# What rules govern using @MOdify and @Query in JPA Repository?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Now that my project is successfully completed, we are trying to document lessons learned. One that still confuses me is the following:

We have a database of addresses, and needed to autocomplete when a User started typing in a street name. Using JPA repository, we implemented a PString class (simply a persistent wrapper for a String), and then implemented this interface:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "locations", path = "locations")
public interface LocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, Integer>, LocationRepositoryCustom {
   List<Location> findByStreetNameAndCommunity_ID(@Param("street") String streetName, @Param("commId") Integer commId);

   @Modifying
   @Query("select distinct x.streetName from Location x where x.streetName like :street%")
   List<PString> findStreetNameStartingWith(@Param("street") String streetName);
}
```

Trying to call locations/search/findStreetNameStartingWith?street=N%20College over the web resulted in:

{"cause":null,"message":"PersistentEntity must not be null!"}

However, we added a controller to call the method:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/custom/locations")
public class LocationController {

   @Autowired
   private LocationRepository repo;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/findStreetNamesStartingWith", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public List<PString> findStreetNameStartingWith(
        @Param("streetName") String streetName) {

      return repo.findStreetNameStartingWith(streetName);
   }
}
```

Calling /custom/locations/findStreetNamesStartingWith?streetName=N%20Coll returns the expected three results. Why does the method not work if called directly, but runs like a greyhound when we pipe it through a controller?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configured [Spring Data REST](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/) properly, like adding the `RepositoryRestConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomizedRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

  @Override
  public RepositoryRestConfiguration config() {
    RepositoryRestConfiguration config = super.config();
    config.setBasePath("/custom");
    return config;
  }
}
```