# Spring Data Rest executes query but returns 500 internal Server Error

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using spring boot and spring data rest and I am facing a 500 internal server error, but no messages are displayed in console.

I have the following:

ProdutoVendaRepository.java

```
public interface ProdutoVendaRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ProdutoVenda, Integer> {

@Query("SELECT new br.com.contoso.model.VendaPorFamilia(b.nome, SUM(i.valorMultiplicado)) FROM ProdutoVenda i JOIN i.produto o JOIN o.familia b WHERE b.nome LIKE 'foo' GROUP BY b.nome")
List <VendaPorFamilia> teste();
}
```

VendaPorFamilia.java

```
public class VendaPorFamilia {

private String nome;

private double valorTotal;

public VendaPorFamilia(String nome, double valorTotal) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
}

//getters and setters
```

ProdutoVenda.java

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "INV1")
public class ProdutoVenda {

@Id
@Column(name = "LineNum")
private int id;

@Column(name = "ItemCode")
private String codigo;

@Column(name = "Quantity")
private double quantidade;

@Column(name = "Price")
private double precoUnitario;

@Column(name = "LineTotal")
private double valorMultiplicado;

@Column(name = "Dscription")
private String descricao;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ItemCode", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private Produto produto;

//getters and setters
```

When I try to

```
curl -v  -X GET -H "X-AUTH-TOKEN: TokenFoo"  
http://localhost:8080/api/produtoVendas/search/teste
```

The log shows that the query was executed:

```
2015-06-16 17:05:45.884 DEBUG 7892 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1]         org.hibernate.SQL                        
: select familia2_.ItmsGrpNam as col_0_0_, sum(produtoven0_.LineTotal) as col_1_0_ from 
INV1 produtoven0_ inner join OITM produto1_ on produtoven0_.ItemCode=produto1_.ItemCode 
inner join OITB familia2_ on produto1_.ItmsGrpCod=familia2_.ItmsGrpCod where    
familia2_.ItmsGrpNam like 'foo' group by familia2_.ItmsGrpNam
```

But I receive a:

```
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Tue, 16 Jun 2015 20:05:46 GMT
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

I don´t know what to do, I´ve tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work.
And Yes, when I execute the exact same generated query in MsSQL server, it returns the wanted value.
All other repositories work without problems...

Thanks for your time and help!

## EDIT: The debug  log shows the folllowing:

```html
2015-06-17 15:25:58.670 DEBUG 8667 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/api/produtoVendas/search/teste]
2015-06-17 15:25:58.674 DEBUG 8667 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /api/produtoVendas/search/teste
2015-06-17 15:25:58.678 DEBUG 8667 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/api/produtoVendas/search/teste]
2015-06-17 15:25:58.692 DEBUG 8667 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/api/produtoVendas/search/teste] is: -1
2015-06-17 15:25:58.758 DEBUG 8667 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select familia2_.ItmsGrpNam as col_0_0_, sum(produtoven0_.LineTotal) as col_1_0_ from INV1 produtoven0_ inner join OITM produto1_ on produtoven0_.ItemCode=produto1_.ItemCode inner join OITB familia2_ on produto1_.ItmsGrpCod=familia2_.ItmsGrpCod where familia2_.ItmsGrpNam like ‘foo’ group by familia2_.ItmsGrpNam
2015-06-17 15:25:58.836 DEBUG 8667 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null!
2015-06-17 15:25:58.839 DEBUG 8667 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ExceptionMessage> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler.handleMiscFailures(java.lang.Exception)
2015-06-17 15:25:58.856 DEBUG 8667 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2015-06-17 15:25:58.857 DEBUG 8667 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum... 
This is strange but I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131338/what-rules-govern-using-modify-and-query-in-jpa-repository) and added a controller to call the method and it worked like a charm...

Obv this is not a fix, but it is a good workaround...

EDIT: The error happens because it is expecting an entity, so all I had to do was annotate VendaPorFamilia with @Entity.

Comment: Thinking about it, after all it makes sense, since Spring Data Rest (JPA) deppends on Hibernate, and Hibernate is an ORM (Object Relational Mapping), and entities are the objects hibernate deal with. So annotating a class with @Entity is the "way to tell" Hibernate, hey, you have this class available to use for your operations.

Answer (score 1):

Put a debugger on the line where connection is established with the database.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I managed to log some debug level and edited my question with the new info, any ideas?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this, but having defined the repository, extending PagingAndSortingRepository<ProdutoVenda, Integer> and expecting the results of a query as some other class than ProdutoVenda, i don't think it is allowed.

Comment: Actually you can, @SalvadorJuanMartinez, see my answer for details